# Disable access to Amplify App from default domain and keep custom domain

Tags: aws-amplify, amazon-route53

I have an app in Amplify that currently has a custom domain attached. I can access the app fine, all seems to be working good on this, but I just tried accessing the default Amplify subdomain (master.something.amplifyapp.com) and this works also.

I would like to either remove this subdomain or redirect it to the custom domain so that users can only access the app from the custom URL.

Looked through documentation, other questions online and cannot seem to find anything related to this. I only found a delete-domain-association page, but unsure if this is actually the way to do it https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/amplify/delete-domain-association.html

Below is how the app looks in domain management:

[image: amplify console]

Is there a best practice on how this should be done? Should it be redirected, should it be removed or something completely different?

Thank you! I appreciate any comment

I have tried looking for similar questions and through documentation.

Comment: Hi! You able to find the solution to this?